# Why can't we use file name to query excel file on Google Drive?

Tags: android, file, google-sheets, filenames

I have an app where I want to query excel on Google Drive as and when a new excel with 'a fixed file name format' is added to the drive. Why does Google not allow us to query the file by filename instead of file id?

For example my app queries a file names August2016.xls and next month it should automatically look for a new file with file name September2016.xls. Currently this is not possible because the application should have the file id. Am I missing something? Is it possible too query a Google Drive file by file name?

Answer (score 1):

The "getFilesByName" function of the "Folder" class should work:

```
var theXLSFile = null;

// the id of the folder that has the excel files.
var FOLDER_ID = "xxxxxxxxx"; 

// alternatively, could use "getFoldersByName".
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId); 

var FILE_NAME = "September2016.xls";
var files = folder.getFilesByName(FILE_NAME);
if (files.length > 0)
    theXLSFile = files[0];
```

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFilesByName(String)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @opowell your answer helped me find the correct Google API. I am doing android development and here are the links to get started on Google Drive API & getFile function.
1) https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started
2) Querying for Files using com.google.android.gms.drive.query package - https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries
3) Google sample- https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/